# Strong Private Key Protection being ignored

Tags: certificate, windows-10

I've tested installing a certificate with Strong Private Key Protection on Windows 10 Enterprise and confirmed when the VPN software tries to access it, Windows prompts me to enter the password I set during the private key import process.

When I run through the same steps on one install of Windows 10 Home machine, the VPN software (same version) gets access to the certificate without me having entered my Strong Private Key Protection password despite it having been set during import. When I test with a different install of Windows 10 Home, Strong Private Key Protection works as expected.

I've tried with multiple passwords in case Windows was doing something stupid like auto-filling it with one which was identical to the Windows user password.

I've also tried deleting the cert from the user store and connecting the VPN, but the VPN as expected then complains that it can't authenticate, so I know that the certificate I'm installing is the one that's being used for authentication. After reinstalling the certificate with Strong Private Key Protection, it goes right back to automatically signing in to the VPN without prompting for the password to be entered.

So, any ideas how to make it work on the one machine where it doesn't?

Comment: Could it be that the logged on Windows user has an empty password?

Comment: @Gerrit the Strong Key Protection password is separate from the Windows user password - it's a password that you pick when importing the certificate and is not necessarily related to any other password on the system. As it happens though, the user also does not have an empty Windows password.

Comment: It's not really independent. Strong Key Protection is done by the DPAPI and the DPAPI creates a master secret derived from the Windows password. If you have a very simple Windows password, then DPAPI protection is useless. And if you have a password policy that requires a minimum number of characters, you will find that this same policy is applied to the Strong Key Protection.   Could it be that on this Windows Home system it has been tried to apply a local security policy? You see that a lot on forums.